# Scope Issue: double array not accessible in if statement

Tags: c, arrays

I have a class method that is supposed to take an object and populate a few values in place. This is at the stage of functional demonstration, so the implementation will be better later. right now I just would like this to work.

In the code below, the districtID integer is successfully passed to the if statements. The rgb double array does not make it into the if statement scope. The values set at initialization make it all the way to the districtPoint.color without getting set inside the if statement.

the code below will not compile as is. I would like to know how to get the rgb variable to be visible within the if statement scope.

(note: I tried the naive solution of initializing the variables within the if statement. This clears the error, but doesn't let the new rgb variables out of the if scope)

```
// This method populates properties
+(void)setContantPropertiesForID:(DistrictPoint *)districtPoint
{
    int districtID = [districtPoint.districtID intValue];
    double rgb[3] = {0,0,0};

    if (districtID == 1) {
        districtPoint.title = @"District 1";
        rgb = {1.0,0.0,0.0};                    // error is expected expression
    } else if (districtID == 2) {
        districtPoint.title = @"District 1";
        rgb = {0.0,1.0,0.0};
    } else if (districtID == 3) {
        districtPoint.title = @"District 1";
        rgb = {0.0,0.0,1.0};
    } else {
        districtPoint.title = nil;
        rgb = {1.0,1.0,1.0};                    // error condition
    }

    districtPoint.color = [UIColor colorWithRed:rgb[0] green:rgb[1] blue:rgb[2] alpha:0.5];
}
```

Comment: This is not an Objective-C question. It is not a variable-scope question. And it has nothing to do with iOS either. It is a simple C language question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the if statement. You can use the curly-braces notation to set an array's elements only when initializing (as you do, in fact, earlier in the code).

Comment: Thank you, I've been fighting that one for 45 minutes. Simple question, simple answer. I'll accept as soon as StackOverflow lets me

Comment: It's a good idea to know C before messing with Objective-C. I always recommend keeping a copy of Kernighan and Ritchie by you at all times. I certainly do!